# Does anyone know why this issue has occurred? It says that o have not given a Y argument, I just want to know if the mistake is on this line or not ty

Tags: c#

[image]

```
probs[o] = Math.Round((100 * (1 - Math.Pow(1 - ((9 * sumanti + 4 * sumlips + slip[o] + 4) / 100)), chance[o])),1);
```

There is a red underline in 'pow' in Math.Pow and it says there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of Math.Power[double,double]'.

I was just wondering if there seems to be an issue on this line and if there isn't I can go to other areas of my code but it would be harder to explain so i was just looking for help on this line, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Math.Pow(1 - ((9 * sumanti + 4 * sumlips + slip[0] + 4) / 100))`.

Let's break it down.

You are basically calling `Math.Pow(x)` where `x` is `1 - ((9 * sumanti + 4 * sumlips + slip[0] + 4) / 100)`. However `Math.Pow` function accepts two parameters `x` and `y`, where x is the base and y is the exponent.

I think you just got confused from all that brace madness... Maybe break it into  smaller pieces each on 1 line?

Comment: yes, this. Use variables to compute intermediate values and make your code easier to read..